# FFMPEG Track Number not written

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, id3

How can I write the track number when re-encoding an audio file using ffmpeg? Currently, I have the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "in.wav" -acodec libmp3lame -aq 0 -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "out.mp3"
```

but the only tag that is not written is the track number.

Comment: You should always include your complete ffmpeg console output too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **metadata** parameter:

```
ffmpeg -i "in.wav" -acodec libmp3lame -aq 0 -metadata track="X/Y" -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "out.mp3"
```

Where **X** is the number of the track, out of **Y** total tracks.

> **‘-metadata[:metadata_specifier] *key=value (output,per-metadata)*’**
>
> Set a metadata key/value pair.
>
> An optional metadata_specifier may be given to set metadata on streams or chapters. See -map_metadata documentation for details.
>
> This option overrides metadata set with -map_metadata. It is also possible to delete metadata by using an empty value.
>
> For example, for setting the title in the output file:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata title="my title" out.flv
> ```
>
> To set the language of the first audio stream:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng OUTPUT
> ```
>
> <sup>[**Source**: *FFmpeg documentation, paragraph 5.4 "Main Options"*](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that. Any reason why it's not automatically transferred like the other tags?

Comment: @StevenFrost Hard to say without speculating; maybe there's some invalid data in there that it cannot parse? I haven't looked at depth how FFmpeg extracts the metadata already present, sorry!